# windows SDK socket use IE proxy setting to connect internet

Tags: windows, sockets, internet-explorer, visual-c++, proxy

I have a C\S program that the client use HTTP proxy server to connect server. We ask the user to input the proxy server IP address, port, the username, and password. Then use Authorization: Basic  method to connect server.

But now we want to auto detect IE proxy server settings, and use the IE proxy settings to connect our server.  We can get the IE proxy server IP address and port from the registry, but can't get the username  and password. So how to use the IE proxy setting to connect internet?  (Maybe I should use Authorization: Negotiate to connect HTTP proxy server.)

Many other software has this feature:

> [image]

Comment: Who requires authentication -- proxy or your server? WinHTTP does not support proxy authentication, so IE would not work with authenticated proxies natively.

Comment: Thanks!HTTP proxy server need authentication. If user input the user name and password,we can connect the proxy server. But now we want to auto detect the IE proxy setting, and then use the IE proxy setting information to connect the proxy server. How to do?

Comment: You may be looking for `InternetQueryOption` and its options `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY`, `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME` and `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_PASSWORD`